# Passing javascript variable to php file

Tags: php, javascript

I can't find the best way to pass a JavaScript variable to use in a PHP file.

I found this function `wp_localize_script()`, but it does exactly the contrary.

Is there a way to pass a JavaScript variable to PHP?

Comment: This isn't a WordPress specific question and is probably better off on [stack overflow proper](http://stackoverflow.com).  That said, the answer is no, not without making another request to the server.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php) on stack overflow.

Comment: In wordpress, to respect best practices

Comment: What exactly are you trying to get from javascript?

Comment: the post id that I have hosted in an attribute

Comment: The post id should already be available from the php end.  See [get_the_ID()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID).  If it's not, could you post some example code that we could take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

You could use cookies - set in JS, and read from PHP.
Another way can be using an AJAX request to get the variable value.